# How do I achieve self reference in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a Table Department that references itself. To build a hierarchy, each Department in the hierarchy must reference the top level Department.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

> *I've used the below code to establish parent child relationship for all the departments.*
>
> *In my database ParentId specifies if the department have any top level departments in the hierarchy?*

```
public void ConfigureDepartmentContext(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Department>(department=>
     {
         department.HasKey(a => new { a.Id });
         department.Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
         department.Property(a => a.Name).HasColumnName("Department_Name");
         department.Property(a => a.ParentId ).HasColumnName("Parent_Id ");
     });

     modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
          .HasOne(f => f.Department)
          .WithOne(f => f.Department)
          .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentId);
}
```

**I am getting below error**

> cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a delegate
>   type

Comment: should I use   modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
                .Property(f => f.ParentId)
                .HasDefaultValueSql()? <br/> if so what should be the parameter for HasDefaultValueSql(..)?<br/> I am using oracle as my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `ModelBuilder` for `Department` as follows:

```
public void ConfigureDepartmentContext(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Department>(department=>
     {
        department.HasKey(a => new { a.Id });
        department.Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        department.Property(a => a.Name).HasColumnName("Department_Name");
        department.Property(a => a.ParentId ).HasColumnName("Parent_Id ");
     });

     // Here is the ForeignKey configuration

     modelBuilder.HasOne(d => d.Department)
       .WithOne().HasForeignKey<Department>(d => d.ParentId)
       .IsRequired(false);
}
```